# What technique is used to modify one object's mesh in coordination with an adjacent object's mesh?

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, constraints

I would like to make a comparative anatomy primitive that I can use as a sculpting base for various animals. Most quadripeds share the same basic surface anatomy plan with differences in proportion, scale and to some extent numbers of anatomic components (for example horses feet have one toe whereas dogs have 5). In the attached image I have tried applying an armature to the bone elements and separate armatures to the muscle elements with constraints on the muscle armature bones relating to the bone armature bones. Unfortunately I am not able to control all meshes adequately with this approach. I have also tried using lattice deformations on the various objects with similar lack luster results. As a minimum I would like to be able to change scale of a bone and have it's scale affect attached muscles. Since I am a complete NOOB at animation I expect there is something I am missing here. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.[image: simple canine anatomy test]

Comment: Try the soft body simulator.